# How do i import/link information from classA to classB in XCode

Tags: xcode

Does anyone know how i can import information from example ClassA.h and ClassA.m to ClassB.h and ClassB.m in Xcode. I've tried #import "ClassA.h" in ClassB, but apparently it isn't enough. Also i've put in ClassB.m a @ClassA method, but that doesn't work also. I'm quite new to XCode, so this could be a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Communication between objects is Object Oriented Programming 101. It would probably be a better use of your time to start off with a few Objective-C tutorials to get the basics down.

There's some decent stuff at http://cocoadevcentral.com/